# Programmatically set Spinner VISIBLE and enabled

Tags: android, spinner

I have a dynamic Android form with dynamic fields behaviour.

Example: If user fills field A, show field B and hides field C.

I'm using methods `view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` and `view.setEnabled(boolean)` for this purpose. This approach works for `RadioGroup` and `EditText`, but don't work for `Spinner` component. 
The spinner is set to visible, but is always disabled. 
The method .setEnable(true) don't cause any effect.

I need to show the spinner enabled.
If the spinner was visible, the setEnabled() works. But if the spinner was invisible, this 2 commands together don't work.

```
spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
spinner.setEnabled(Boolean.TRUE)
```

[]'s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide more details. The following code shows you how you can show/hide or enable/disable the spinner.

```
boolean visibility = true;
    boolean enabled = true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
        String[] animals = {"cats","dogs","lines","rats"};
        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,animals));
        linearLayout.addView(spinner);
        Button visiblity = new Button(this);
        visiblity.setText("VisibilityButton");
        linearLayout.addView(visiblity);
        setContentView(linearLayout);
        visiblity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(visibility){
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    visibility = false;
                }
                else{
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    visibility = true;
                }
            }
        });
        Button enabledButton = new Button(this);
        enabledButton.setText("EnabledButton");
        linearLayout.addView(enabledButton);
        enabledButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(enabled){
                    spinner.setEnabled(false);
                    enabled = false;
                }
                else{
                    spinner.setEnabled(true);
                    enabled = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```